# How to map multiline (each line has the same format using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I was trying to map each line content using perl, and each line has the same format.

I have successful map the first line, but once I add $ after regex, everything goes wrong. however if I delete the $, the reguar expression can only match the first line and igorn the rest

Here is the content

```
$bar ="0 qid:85 1:0.666667 2:0.666666 3:0.857143 #docid = 579
0 qid:85 1:0.666667 2:0.666666 3:0.857143 #docid = 579";

m/^([0-2])[\s]qid\:(\d+).*?\#docid[\s]=[\s](\d+)+$/
```

Comment: above is the regex I used, if I add "$" I will got error 
if I delete $, only the first line can be matched

Comment: When you add `$` then your regex expects the input to end but since you also have digits lying which are not yet matched, your match starts failing. So for matching that number just adding `\d+` will make your regex match successfully but I see someone already updated your post and already changed your initial regex and added `(\d+)+` where as only `\d+` was suffice. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/ERN8HO/1) Here it matches all the lines with little modification in regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need `/m` to change the definition of `^` and `$` to match your needs.

  - `^` normally only matches at the start of the string. With `/m`, it also matches after line feeds.
  - `$` normally only matches at a line feed at the end of the string and at the end of the string. With `/m`, it also matches at any line feed.
- You need `/g` to get all the matches (rather than just the first).
- `[\s]` is weird way of writing `\s`.
- `(\d+)+` (at the end) should be `(\d+)`.
- I've added whitespace to the pattern to make more readable, which is made possible using `/x`.

Fixed:

```
while ( $bar =~ /^([0-2]) \s qid:(\d+) \s .*? \s \#docid \s = \s (\d+)$/mgx ) {
   my ($foo, $qid, $docid) = ($1, $2, $3);
   ...
}
```